# .If you have 6 jobs can we run some jobs in window slave and some jobs in Linux slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

.If you have 6 jobs can we run some jobs in window slave and some jobs in Linux slave?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run agent nodes on any OS that supports Java. You can also set labels to the slaves and specify this label as the agent when you are creating the pipeline so that the correct job runs on the correct VM. The way you would connect to Linux VMs vs Windows would be different, but after the initial setup, the rest of the steps should be similar.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/